# tinymce-rails no implicit conversion of String into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-rails

I'm trying to use the [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) gem, and have followed all the instructions to set it up. The last step is using the tinymce helper `<%= tinymce %>` which is throwing the exception `no implicit conversion of String into Hash`

There was an issue about this, but the guy solved his own issue without saying what the problem was, except that it was an issue with the `tinymce.yml` file.

Here is my YAML file:

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen

default:
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
  theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
    - tablecontrols
  plugins:
    - table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, but I was able to get this working by just deleting all the default stuff in the YAML file. I'm not sure what those are supposed to do, but it all works fine for me, so give that a try.

I assume someone here will have a better answer.